# Notification message's delay before hide

Tags: macos, script, notifications

I made a script to upload images, it shows a notification, but it stays on screen for a very long time until I close it by click.

Is there a way to decrease the delay for this notification?

Comment: Perhaps share how the script is calling the notifications?

Comment: display notification input with title "Uploader" subtitle "Image iploaded"